# Stick of length 6 is broken into two pieces. Expected value of ratio of shorter to longer

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Jen’s dog broke her six inch long pencil off at a random point on the pencil. Find the density function and the expected value of the ratio of the shorter piece and the longer piece.

$X$ is longer piece and $Y$ is smaller

$U \sim U(0,6)$

Define $X = \text{max}\{U, 6-U\}$

so that

$$X =
\begin{cases}
6-U,  & 0 < U < 3 \\
U, & 3 \leq U < 6
\end{cases}
$$

It follows that

$$X = \frac{6 + |2U - 6|}{2}$$

Similarly

$$Y = \frac{6 - |6-2U|}{2}$$

Let $Z=Y/X$

$$F_Z(z) = P (Z \leq z)$$

$$=P\left(\frac{6 + |2U - 6|}{6 - |6-2U|} \leq z \right)$$

I don't know what to do next

Comment: For $x\in [0,3]$ the ratio is $\frac {6-x}x$, for $x\in [3,6]$ it is $\frac x{6-x}$ so just split the integral into two parts. (But does the integral converge?)

Comment: Won't it be the opposite? x/6-x for [0,3]

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509254.

Comment: I assumed you wanted $\frac {\text {Longer}}{\text {Shorter}}$. If you meant the opposite, just flip the two fractions.