# Splitting $2n + 1$ cards, what is the expected ratio of a size of the smaller deck to the bigger deck?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

Assuming equal probability of the deck where the split is.

I can find the expected size of the smaller deck of card is $\frac{1+n}{2}$, but I am not sure how the find the expected ratio in a closed form of $n$.

Fundamentally, it would be something like $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2n+1-i}$. Not sure if there is a closed form. Maybe there is a different approach.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there's a fully closed form; but you can write it as
$$
\frac1n \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} \frac{2n+1-i}i = \frac{2n+1}n \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} \frac1i - \frac1n \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} 1 = \frac{2n+1}n (H_{2n}-H_n) - 1
$$
in terms of the harmonic numbers $H_m$. (As a side comment, note that the limit of the right-hand side as $n\to\infty$ equals $2\log 2-1$, consistent with [the question lulu pointed to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118773/broken-stick-average-of-the-ratio-of-the-shortest-piece-to-the-largest-piece) in a comment.)

Comment: +1.  From your exact result using harmonic numbers it seems this is $\big(2\log(2)-1\big)\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)-\frac{1}{8n^2} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$